# Error while exporting data through Mappia Publisher in QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, export, mappia-publisher

I installed Mappia Publisher in QGIS 3.14 and try to share some data. It works until almost the end. It gives me a Python error. I do not know why. Also, it takes me almost two hours to run.

```
Finished map tile generation. Uploading changes to Github.
Github found commiting to your account.
Git: Pulling remote repository current state.
Elapsed 2s on this step.
Git: Add all generated tiles to your repository.
Elapsed 30s: Please wait, identifying changes on your repository.
Elapsed 61s: Please wait, identifying changes on your repository.
Elapsed 92s: Please wait, identifying changes on your repository.
Elapsed 114s on this step.
Git: Committing changes.
Elapsed 9s on this step.
Git: Pushing modifications to remote repository.
Elapsed 0s on this step.
Error, publication failed! Reporting error to Mappia development team.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mappia_publisher\mappia_publisher_algorithm.py", line 792, in processAlgorithm
return self.generate(writer, parameters, context, feedback)
File "C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mappia_publisher\mappia_publisher_algorithm.py", line 619, in generate
GitHub.publishTilesToGitHub(writer.folder, ghUser, ghRepository, feedback, self.version, ghPassword)
File "C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mappia_publisher\GitHub.py", line 385, in publishTilesToGitHub
GitHub.pushChanges(repo, user, repository, password, feedback)
File "C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mappia_publisher\GitHub.py", line 353, in pushChanges
return GitInteractive.pushChanges(repo, user, repository, password, feedback)
File "C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mappia_publisher\GitHub.py", line 682, in pushChanges
GitHub.getGitPassUrl(user, repository, password), "master:refs/heads/master")
File "C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mappia_publisher\UTILS.py", line 144, in runLongTask
return job.result()
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 425, in result
return self.__get_result()
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
raise self._exception
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File "C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mappia_publisher\git\cmd.py", line 542, in <lambda>
return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mappia_publisher\git\cmd.py", line 1005, in _call_process
return self.execute(call, **exec_kwargs)
File "C:/Users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\mappia_publisher\git\cmd.py", line 822, in execute
raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value, stdout_value)
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe') failed due to: exit code(1)
cmdline: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe push https://liaduarte:0a18394b1e7b22cc57d853d1f920b6032dbc93e9@github.com/liaduarte/Mappia_Example/ master:refs/heads/master
stderr: 'error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://...@github.com/.../Mappia_Example/''

Execution failed after 1162.77 seconds
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get, can you be so kind and describe this problem more in details? As well as can you tell more about your data, how big is it?

Comment: I add the error to the main Question.